# Clean up [domain]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) tag currently provides very little value, because it's an ambiguous term that refers to several unrelated concepts in vastly different fields. Based on a very quick look, it appears that most of the questions fall into one of three categories:

- questions about Internet domain names
- the software engineering concept of domains (a la [domain-driven-design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design) [domain-model](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-model))
- the SQL notion of a domain, per `CREATE DOMAIN`, as in [To Domain or not to Domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110316/to-domain-or-not-to-domain)

(Full disclose: I'm not well-antiquated with the latter two uses, so I don't know how related they are, if at all.)

These separate uses should probably get their own tags, and `[domain]` should possibly be blacklisted to prevent further vague misuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) is now six separate tags:

[domain-driven-design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design): Covers the design methodology. [ddd](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddd) turns into this.

[domain-model](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-model): Business domains and the like are covered here.

[domain-name-system](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-name-system): Covers DNS, Domain name service is a common mix-up and turns into this if anyone tries it.

[domain-objects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-objects): Covers domain objects in Java and similar.

[domain-specific-languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-specific-languages): Covers DSLs and related concepts.

[sql-domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-domain): Covers the concept of Domains in SQL.

That should take care of everything. I retagged and merged a bunch of things. Let the mod team know if there are any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's a mess.  Some of the questions should probably be closed and/or deleted.  That simplifies retagging them.

For the domain names I've created the tag [domain-name-system](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-name-system) with a tag wiki for this and moved some questions into it while removing the domain tag.

Other questions had multiple domain tags ([ddd](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddd) *and* [domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain)) for which the domain tag could be removed.

And its still a mess... I've only retagged a few of them.